# Install files using symbolic links with CMAKE

Tags: cmake, installation

I have converted my project to use `cmake`.  During development I'd like to be able to install the product not the normal way, but let (notably) the installed data files be symbolic links to the source tree.

The project is SWI-Prolog which provides functionality to directly navigate and edit source files.  If I use this to extend and fix the system libraries however I'm editing the installed *copy* that I then need to copy back to the sources before I can commit.

I know I can override functions in `cmake`, but in this case we are dealing with cmake code that is generated.

Comment: You want to replace `install(FILES)` functionality with a creating a symlinks, but without editing `CMakeLists.txt`, am I correctly understand the problem? I know no CMake "switch" for perform that, neither a command-line option nor a variable which can be set in the command line. May be it is possible with some postprocessing after the installing the project. In that postprocessing one may *somehow* obtain info about files being installed, filter the ones installed from the source tree, and replace their installed file with a symlink.

Comment: I'm happy to edit `CMakeLists.txt`.   As I understand it though, `install(FILES ...` generates `cmake_install.cmake` and the subsequent `make` (or `ninja`) calls `cmake -P cmake_install.cmake`.  `cmake_install.cmake` calls `file(INSTALL ...` to do the real work.  I was considering to create a `cmake_ln_install.cmake` that redefines `file(INSTALL ...` and then includes `cmake_install.cmake`.  Would that be doable?   A last resort is indeed to examine `install_manifest.txt` and rediscover the relation between source and installed files and do something with that.

Comment: The above seems plausible, except that redefining `file()` fails as it is at some places passed empty strings.  Posted as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52480737/pass-empty-strings-in-cmake

Answer (score 0):

If you're using CMake 3.22 (2021-11-18) or later, try setting the environment variable [`CMAKE_INSTALL_MODE`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/envvar/CMAKE_INSTALL_MODE.html) to `REL_SYMLINK`.

E.g.:

```bash
export CMAKE_INSTALL_MODE=REL_SYMLINK
```

Then run your cmake build process as normal:

```bash
cd _build
cmake -DFOO=bar ..
make install DESTDIR=/path/to/root
```

This will install relative symlinks in `/path/to/root` pointing to files inside the build directory as well as the source directory. Basically everything that would be installed normally except it's a symbolic link. For example:

```
/path/to/root/usr/include/mylib/mylib.h -> ../../../../src/mylib/mylib.h
/path/to/root/usr/lib64/mylib.so.0.10.0 -> ../../../_build/target/mylib.so.0.10.0
```

Cmake accepts a few different values for `CMAKE_INSTALL_MODE`:

- `COPY`, empty or unset
  Duplicate the file at its destination. This is the default behavior.
- `ABS_SYMLINK`
  Create an absolute symbolic link to the source file at the destination. Halt with an error if the link cannot be created.
- `ABS_SYMLINK_OR_COPY`
  Like ABS_SYMLINK but fall back to silently copying if the symlink couldn't be created.
- `REL_SYMLINK`
  Create a relative symbolic link to the source file at the destination. Halt with an error if the link cannot be created.
- `REL_SYMLINK_OR_COPY`
  Like `REL_SYMLINK` but fall back to silently copying if the symlink couldn't be created.
- `SYMLINK`
  Try as if through `REL_SYMLINK` and fall back to `ABS_SYMLINK` if the referenced file cannot be expressed using a relative path. Halt with an error if the link cannot be created.
- `SYMLINK_OR_COPY`
  Like `SYMLINK` but fall back to silently copying if the symlink couldn't be created.

Comment: Thanks for pointing at this!   I have implemented a rather complicated way around.    This is not yet an option as forcing requirement for CMake 22 will cause too many people to be unhappy :(     In due time it is likely to simplify things.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the version requirement, I didn't realize it was implemented so recently (2021-11-18). Updated my answer to explain that it needs 3.22 or later.