# Pass empty strings in cmake?

Tags: cmake

I'm trying to redefine a function in cmake.  But, only some signatures for this function.  If I do not recognise the signature I simply want to call the original with all original arguments.  This works fine, unless the function os called with empty strings (`""`) as arguments.  The problem can be illustrated like this:

```
function(y)
  list(LENGTH ARGN len)
  message("y got ${len} elements: ${ARGN}")
endfunction()

function(x)
  list(LENGTH ARGN len)
  message("x got ${len} elements: ${ARGN}")
  y(${ARGN})
endfunction()

x(a b "")
x(a "" c)
```

Save the above to `x.cmake` and run `cmake -P x.cmake`, which prints

```
> cmake -P x.cmake
x got 3 elements: a;b;
y got 2 elements: a;b
x got 3 elements: a;;c
y got 2 elements: a;c
```

I.e., `y` doesn't get the empty string and my redefined function stops working.  Any clue how to pass **all** arguments, including empty strings?

Real use case is trying to redefine `file` to change the installation.  You're alternative doesn't seem to work for that:

```
function(file)
  message("Calling file(${ARGN})")
  _file("${ARGN}")
endfunction()

include("cmake_install.cmake")
```

This results in

```
> cmake -P cmake_ln_install.cmake
-- Install configuration: "RelWithDebInfo"
Calling file(RPATH_CHECK;FILE;/home/janw/cmake/linux/lib/swipl/bin/x86_64-linux/swipl;RPATH;/home/janw/cmake/linux/lib/swipl/lib/x86_64-linux)
CMake Error at cmake_ln_install.cmake:3 (_file):
  _file must be called with at least two arguments.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  src/cmake_install.cmake:43 (file)
  cmake_install.cmake:42 (include)
  cmake_ln_install.cmake:6 (include)
```

Comment: Hm, among CMake functions which I know, an empty string (`""`) is accepted only as a *positional* parameter, so you may define the function as `function(x param1 param2 param3)` and have direct access to these parameters. Exception is a function like `set`, which you unlikely want to intercept.

Answer (score 5):

Changing

```
y(${ARGN})
```

to

```
y("${ARGN}")
```

makes it behave as you expect.

Comment: Looks convincing, but doesn't do the job.  The real function I try to redefine is `file`.  I edited the question above to reflect what doesn't work

Comment: Yes, this shouldn't work. Whatever is passed inside quotes is treated as a single argument by the callee. However, if the callee itself will iterate over `${ARGN}`, it will find all arguments as if they have been passed separately. @JanWielemaker: You may try to define `function(file arg1 arg2)` and call original function with `_file(${arg1} ${arg2} "${ARGN}")`. This should pass a check for the parameter's number.

Comment: I thought about that, but then we get this (sorry for the bad formatting) `-- Install configuration: "RelWithDebInfo"
Calling file(RPATH_CHECK FILE /ufs/wielemak/lib/swipl/bin/x86_64-linux/swipl;RPATH;/ufs/wielemak/lib/swipl/lib/x86_64-linux)
CMake Error at cmake_ln_install.cmake:3 (_file):
  _file RPATH_CHECK not given RPATH option.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  src/cmake_install.cmake:43 (file)
  cmake_install.cmake:42 (include)
  cmake_ln_install.cmake:6 (include)'  (does anyone know where to find the soruce for `file`?  That may hint at what is happening.

Comment: Downloaded the source.  The `file` command is written in C++ and it seems that processing additional arguments works different there.  That probably explains why `_file(${arg1} ${arg2} "${ARGN}")` does not work.  Back to square one: how to call a function from its name and arguments where the list may contain empty strings?